# Jquery serialize() not working on using two div inside one form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to take user info in two parts using single form and then serialize these values. Here's how I'm doing this in my code-

```
 <form action="">
<div id="11">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" /><br>
</div>

<button id="b1" >Proceed to get next two values</button>

<div id="22" style="display:none">
First name2: <input type="text" name="FirstName2" value="" /><br>
Last name2: <input type="text" name="LastName2" value="" /><br>
</div>

</form>

<button id="b2"  style="display:none">Serialize all form values</button>
<div></div>
```

Thus in the code above i want to display two fields at a time while hiding other two. And then serializing all four values using jquery serialize().
Here's is how i'm trying to handle this in my Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#b1").click(function(){
  $("#11").hide();
  $("#b1").hide();
  $("#22").show();
  $("#b2").show();
});
  $("#b2").click(function(){
    y = $("div").text($("form").serialize());
   alert("output" + y);
   });
});
</script>
```

When i click on button(with id 11) div2 gets display and then it automatically gets disappear. Not sure what mistake i'm making. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has nothing to do with `serialize`.

This code:

```
$("div").text($("form").serialize());
```

Will replace content of every `DIV` in page. To target a specific `DIV` give it an ID. You also need to prevent the butttons from triggering the browser to submit form when clicked. This can be accomplished by setting `type` to `button` or using script to prevent default

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rd5Ac/

You can save code needed to hide/show the buttons if you place buttons within the form `DIV`'s

Comment: That's correct. I got it..actually issue was with 'button' type. Now it's working fine. Thanks a lot.